# Issue with ECS task: ChromeDriverManager().install() gives tuple index out of range

Tags: amazon-ecs

I was using selenium with headless chrome.

I have a docker image. The code works fine when i run the image locally on my pc.

But when i try to run it on the ECS task, its failing saying for

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

the above code is failing with `tuple index out of range`

Strange thing is the same docker image works perfectly fine on my local machine, where as when deployed on the ecs task its failing with the above error